# How can I get a user's rank/position in SQLite3 with a query?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I would like to know what a user's rank is out of all users. Let's say this is the table:

```
UserName | Coins
---------------
Matthew  |  18
Nick     |  12
Cat      |  33
```

Cat has the most coins, so she would be ranked #1 and Nick would be ranked #3. How can I get her rank with a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option here is to use a correlated subquery to find the dense ranks.

```
SELECT
    t1.UserName, 
    t1.Coins,
    t2.rank
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        t1.Coins,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Coins FROM yourTable) t2
         WHERE t2.Coins >= t1.Coins) rank
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Coins FROM yourTable) t1
) t2
    ON t1.Coins = t2.Coins;
```

The above query attempts to handle an edge case where two or more users have the same coin level.  It would assign dense ranks as follows:

```
UserName | Coins | Rank
-----------------------
Cat      |  33   | 1
Matthew  |  18   | 2
Nick     |  12   | 3
Michael  |  12   | 3
Donald   |  12   | 3
Jim      |  10   | 4
Alf      |  10   | 4
```

Comment: SQLite has this special autogenerated column `rowid`.  I wonder if create/select-ing a new simple table sorted by coins, then outputing rowid, solves it... It would break ties though.

Comment: @Paul I don't see how sorting by coins is going to help here.  That might work for row number, but not for rank.